# Dealing csv files with python(reading one csv,based on values need to take decision and write it to another csv file)

Tags: python, csv

I have a requirement wherein I have to deal with **csv files**. There is one folder in which I have **.csv files**(number may vary from 10-15 .csv files) and there is one more **csv file** named `subscription.csv` in which I have data as shown below :

```
Subscription        Type            TotalCost  Managed  Foundation
File1.csv       FullyManaged            N/A         N/A      N/A
File3.csv       PartlyManaged           N/A         N/A      N/A
File4.csv       PartlyManaged           N/A         N/A      N/A
File5.csv       FullyManaged            N/A         N/A      N/A
```

The scenario goes like this :

I have to **read** **subscription.csv** and if **type of subscription** is `FullyManaged` then I have to **sum column K**(column name in data is Cost) which is there in `File1.csv` and I have to **update sum** in `outsubscription.csv` under **total cost coulmn**(will share final layout of `outsubscription.csv`)

If it is `PartlyManaged` then I have to take **sum of column K**(column name in data is Cost), **sum of column O**(column name in data is Mcost) from that particular `.csv(File3.csv)` and I have to **update** this also in `outsubscription.csv` under **Totalcost** and **Manged column**.

And it will go on until `list` of `csv files` does not end.

Final `outsubscription.csv` will looks like this:

```
Subscription        Type            TotalCost  Managed  Foundation
File1.csv       FullyManaged            100        N/A      N/A
File3.csv       PartlyManaged           150         50      N/A
File4.csv       PartlyManaged           150         50      N/A
File5.csv       FullyManaged            150        N/A      N/A
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This code works as expected.

```
import csv

def get_column(rows, col_name):
    col_index = None
    for i in range(len(rows[0])):
        if rows[0][i] == col_name:
            col_index = i
            break

    assert col_index is not None, "Column ({}) not found".format(col_name)
    column_data = [row[col_index] for row in rows[1:]]
    return column_data


def get_csv_rows(csv_file_name):
    with open(csv_file_name) as csvfile:
        data = csv.reader(csvfile)
        return [row for row in data]


def compute_cost():
    rows = get_csv_rows('subscription.csv')
    result_rows = [['Subscription', 'Type', 'TotalCost',
                    'Managed', 'Foundation']]
    for rowindex in range(1, len(rows)):
        fname = rows[rowindex][0]
        frows = get_csv_rows(fname)
        tcost = sum(map(int, get_column(frows, 'Cost')))
        mcost = 'N/A'
        ftype = rows[rowindex][1]
        if ftype == 'PartlyManaged':
            mcost = sum(map(int, get_column(frows, 'MCost')))
        result_row = [fname, ftype, tcost, mcost, rows[rowindex][4]]
        result_rows.append(result_row)


    with open('outsubscription.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
        writer.writerows(result_rows)


compute_cost()
```